# Monit: Customize alert message to include command output

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

I would like to customize the Monit's alert message, so that whenever I get an alert, the email also includes the output of a command like `top`, so that I will already know more details about what might have caused the problem.

Is there a way to do this? The documentation doesn't include anything relevant, and searching wasn't helpful either.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this, from the monit wiki?

```
# Getting top otput by mail on event
check file myfile with path /tmp/fo.bar
  if changed timestamp then exec "/bin/bash -c 'top -bn1 | mail -s top admin@foo.bar'"
```

Link: http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples
(scroll to very bottom)

Comment: Henry, I would have preferred a more "centralized" solution, that would enable me to add ``top``'s output in the ``mail-format`` parameter, so that I would get it in every mail alert sent. From what I read though, this is impossible.

Your solution is an excellent workaround though!

Comment: The problem with this is that the `exec` is executed everytime the condition is asserted, likely resulting in one email every cycle